# How to create an MySQL query alias?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

For example I use this

```
select * from tab1;
```

every 5 minutes.

Is there a way to set up an alias `p` so that I can just do

```
p
```

instead and that query is executed?

Answer (score 3):

This calls for a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), but in your case it isn't much shorter:
`create view p as selecT * From tab1;`
You'd use it as: `select * from p`

It does get more interesting with more complex queries though.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a stored procedure and then call it like `CALL p`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html). You could call it by using:

```
CALL p;
```

This is how to create a stored procedure for the example in your question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p() SELECT * FROM tab1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create stored procedure p with your query

and type

```
   call p
```